# iOS Swift 2 Generate AES Key

Tags: ios, swift, aes

I want to randomly generate an AES 256 key. Swift provides the `SecKeyGeneratePair` which is to generate an asymmetric encryption key. Is there an equivalence for generating a symmetrical encryption key?

Comment: have you found the answer. can you please share the code.

Answer (score 7):

If you are randomly generating the key, all you need to do is use a CSPRNG (cryptographically-secure psuedorandom number generator) to generate an array of 256 bits. You should use [`SecRandomCopyBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1399291-secrandomcopybytes) from the [Randomization Services](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1658565-randomization_services). Calling this with a count of 32 (32 bytes == 256 bits) will yield a suitable key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I looking for a way to generate a key directly into the keychain. So the actual key is not visible from the App.

Comment: The linked page has an example: ```var bytes = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 10)
let status = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytes.count, &bytes)

if status == errSecSuccess { // Always test the status.
    print(bytes)
    // Prints something different every time you run.
}```

Comment: @Andy I executed above code and got this array of bytes [27, -54, 126, -100, 70, -127, 28, -54, -128, -72]. so is this my valid AES256 Key?